# Is it legal to display audio files of singers

Tags: google-play, app-store, copyright-display

recently i developed application for `ios` and `android`. it allows users to upload audio files from their own storage to server . and i have tab into my app for displaying those audios files . most of files like songs and Dj music .. etc ..
does it legal if i upload it on `google play` store and `appstore` ?
Or is this considered copyright infringement?
[image]

Comment: This site has nothing to do with legal issues.  This is a site for programming questions and answers.  Even if someone were to answer your question, I wouldn't think you'd want to trust the opinion of one person who isn't a lawyer.

Comment: and what copyright-display does doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You will be liable for copyright infringement even if it is a user-generated content.

Even if you didn't share copyrighted content or share trademark-infringing content yourself, you may be held responsible if other people do so on your server/app.

[From Google Play Console agreement](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888072?hl=en)

> We also don’t allow apps that encourage or induce infringement of intellectual property rights.

People could report each audio file separately, and your whole app as a 'a tool bypasses copyright technological protection measures'

Comment: in tiktok , any body can take your voice from your videos and use it on it's own video even without any Prior permission  , How do you explain that?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan in TikTok you've already give the app permission to use  your voice, and you can opt out of this. Also, songs are treated in a different way and have much more protection than your voice.

Comment: thanks . but when i said my voice it does not mean my voice at exactly .. maybe i use song as background to my video that i brought it from YouTube . can you please explain on this point ? i don't think they have agreement with all owner songs

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set some terms in you EULA, like, the user have to ensure that they own the full copyright of the audio they upload, and the user grants you to do whatever you want to do with your app. And you need to set a copyright complaint module in your own website and delete what's in your server when anyone claim copyright to any audio in your website